# Liberación de memoria de dos Malloc en C

Tags: c, struct, memoria

Estaba haciendo implementación de un ABB de palabras en C, lo declaré así:

```
typedef struct _nodo{
char *palabra;
struct _nodo *der, *izq;
} Nodo;

typedef Nodo* pNodo;
```

Mi intención es hacer que almacene palabras de N letras. Solo que tengo una duda respecto a la liberación de memoria final que debo hacer:

```
pNodo raiz;
raiz=malloc(sizeof(pNodo));
raiz->palabra = malloc(5*sizeof(char));
strcpy(raiz->palabra, "caca");
raiz->der = raiz->izq = NULL;

//free(raiz->palabra);
free(raiz);
```

La línea comentada no sé si va, esa es mi duda, si ya basta con la de abajo, o si es necesario liberar las dos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta es simple. Debes llamar a `free` la misma cantidad de veces que llamaste a `malloc`. Sino la memoria quedará sin liberar.

Por lo tanto si, es necesario y en ese mismo orden que lo muestras.

---

También tienes un error en la línea:

```
raiz = malloc(sizeof(pNodo));
```

Estás reservando memoria para un puntero.
Lo que en realidad quieres es un `Nodo`.

Si no usarás memoria dinámica lo harías así:

```
Nodo n;
Nodo* ptr = &n;
```

Y no así:

```
Nodo* n;
Nodo* ptr = &n;
```

La otra razón por la que está mal es que el tamaño del tipo `Nodo` no es el mismo que el de un puntero.

Cualquier tipo de puntero ocupa 4 o 8 bytes. `Nodo` necesita espacio para 3 punteros. O sea 12 o 24 bytes.

Lo correcto sería:

```
raiz = malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
```

Nota que la conversión de un puntero de cualquier tipo a `void*` es [implícita](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer#Pointers_to_void). También de `void*` a otro tipo de puntero. [En C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_void) es igual, solo que para convertir de `void*` a otro tipo de puntero necesitas una **conversión explícita**, de lo contrario tendrás errores de compilación.

Comment: ¿El casteo debo hacerlo entonces siempre?, ¿en dado caso podría poner igualmente (pNodo) para reemplazar (Nodo*)?

Comment: @abcLaRry El casteo no es necesario. Eso hace falta solo si estas compilando C con un compilador de C++, ya que C++ no permite el cast implicito de `void*` a otro tipo de puntero.

Comment: @Pablochaches gracias por la corrección. Aún no estoy al tanto de todas las diferencias entre C y C++.